# Code freezing when using simple Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)

Tags: java, linux, shell, fedora

When I run my application and scan for an IP it freezes for some reason. Also, I am not sure if the `Yum` method is exiting once it run the command, or if it lives forever. My target was to make something like `$ ./inLinuxRunMe &`, where it runs in the background, and when the job is done, it kills itself.

I don't think that my `Yum` method is doing this, because it freezes when I start heavy loads such as playing video's etc.

```
public class MyShell
{
    public static String whatIsMyIP = null;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      t = new javax.swing.Timer(10000, new ActionListener() 
      {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {
        /* Scanner: if the ip change, show the new on too. */
        whatIsMyIP = MyShell.Yum("ifconfig eth0 | grep inet").toLowerCase());           
            /* Some logical conditions ... such as if ran then dont run, run once etc..*/ 
            bootMe();
         }
      });
      t.start();

      /* Launch: Main application server, runs forever as server */
      // MyShell.Yum("java -cp myjar.jar launch.MainApplicationAsServer");
    }

    /* Boot loader */
    public static void bootMe() throws IOException
    {
      MyShell.Yum("java -cp myjar.jar launch.MainApplicationAsServer");
    }

    /* Question: How to optimize it? So that, 
             it execute the shell command and quite*/
    public static String Yum(String cmds)
    {
        String value = "";
        try 
        {
          String cmd[] = {"/bin/sh", "-c", cmds };       
          Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);       
          BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(
                                                                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
          String line=reader.readLine(); 

          while(line!=null) 
          { 
            value += line ;
            line=reader.readLine(); 
          } 
          p.waitFor(); 

        } catch(IOException e1) {
        } catch(InterruptedException e2) { 
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which `Yum` call do you want to return, the one in the timer or the one that says "runs forever as server"?

Comment: @Kevin: only the whatIsMyIP returns are kept. Runs forever is only one time launch.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the Yum() method to run your "main application server?" You're starting your server in a second Java VM (so it won't have access to `whatIsMyIP`, since that's in the first VM), and then polling for output from it (building up an ever-increasingly-large string, without using StringBuilder, so your GC will *hurt*). If you really want to start your main server in a separate process, why not just Runtime.exec() it directly, without the line-reader logic? ... or, do you want to run it in the same VM, perhaps? ...Just call launch.MainApplicationAsServer.main() directly?

Comment: @BRPocock: I used Runtime.exec() also and that also caused my freez. But once i drop everything and launched the main server only, it never yet freez. I have to run the Yum() method because when the system start 1) It shows splash screen and wait for ip 2) once ip is ready it launch the main server 3) when system shutdown all is ended. (i do not want to launch main server until the IP is found).

Comment: @Google, I'm pretty sure you don't intend to launch the task in the timer loop, if it "runs forever." Perhaps you want to run the IP address scraper once, then start the timer, then exec the main server, like `whatIsMyIP=MyShell.Yum(...); t.start (); bootMe ();` ?

Comment: @BRPocock: You are right too. But my application is getting launched when you start your machine. The first execute is useless, because in that execution i never had IP (because the routers are slow to provide DHCP ip). Once the System boot, desktop shows then a Splash screen starts showing logo, when the IP is really found, then finally the main server get launched once. Sometime the main server is gets down. In that case the splash screen has a button to re-launch manually once.

Comment: That is a pretty complicated way to determine the local ip address. If you just want the "default" local ip address, you can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost(). If you want to explore all available ip addresses, look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Java API:

```
Constructor Summary
Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)
      Creates a Timer that will notify its listeners every `delay` milliseconds.
```

So it repeats every 10 seconds.  You need to tell it not to repeat:

```
public void setRepeats(boolean flag)

    If flag is false, instructs the Timer to send only one action event to its listeners.

    Parameters:
        flag - specify false to make the timer stop after sending its first action event
```

So:

```
t = new javax.swing.Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {...});
t.setRepeats(false);
t.start();
```

Comment: On a Fedora system, you can use NetworkManager to track available network interfaces, obtain IP addresses, and so forth, including requesting notifications of changes: http://people.redhat.com/dcbw/NetworkManager/NetworkManager%20DBUS%20API.txt has the DBUS API for communicating with it. In general, you can also use InetAddress.getLocalHost() to obtain "an address" of the local machine, I believe.

Comment: I mucked up the URI in my prior comment and don't know how to edit it, sorry.

http://people.redhat.com/dcbw/NetworkManager/NetworkManager%20DBUS%20API.txt

Answer (score 2):

Run you `Yum()` method in a separate thread.

Comment: But he isn't using it for the call that's actually freezing everything (the second one).